# Vector Fields in a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. 
Is there a way to classify manifolds where there exists a vector field that commutes with the laplace beltrami operator?
Thanks

Comment: Clearly Killing vector fields have this property. But in general, I guess that one can think of such vector fields as generators of "isospectralities" (instead of isometries). What would be a nice example of a manifold with such a vector field that is not Killing?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that my statement on "isospectralities" makes sense: the principal symbol of the Laplace operator is the metric itself. So doesn't this imply that every vector field that commutes with the Laplacian must be Killing?

Comment: That is a good point but then should we consider the principal symbol of the commutator? That would be the poisson bracket of the two principal symbols

Answer (score 8):

I give a geometric explanation of the calculations of Willie, which simultaneously elaborates the suggestion of Deane.

The flow of a vector field commuting with Laplacian preserves the Laplacian  and therefore its symbol which is the inverse of the metric (i.e., $g^{ij}$). Then, the flow of the vector field preserves the metric and the vector field is Killing

A related question is

[is $\nabla \cdot ( c^2 \nabla)$ a Laplace-Beltrami operator?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55556/is-nabla-cdot-c2-nabla-a-laplace-beltrami-operator/65681#65681)

Added later: Just have seen that  Tobias Fritz  in his comment which appeared before my answer already had the same explanation.

Answer (score 7):

The commutator is easy enough to compute.

Acting on scalars we have
$$ \begin{align}
[\triangle_g, \mathcal{L}_X] &= [g^{ab} \nabla_a \nabla_b ,\mathcal{L}_X] \\
&= [g^{ab} \nabla_a, \mathcal{L}_X]\nabla_b \\
&= {}^{(X,0)}\pi^{ab} \nabla_a \nabla_b + g^{ab} [\nabla_a, \mathcal{L}_X] \nabla_b \\
&= {}^{(X,0)}\pi^{ab} \nabla_a\nabla_b + g^{ab} {}^{(X,1)}\pi_{ab}^c \nabla_c
\end{align} $$
where the deformation tensors are
$$ {}^{(X,0)}\pi_{ab} = \mathcal{L}_X g_{ab} $$
and 
$$ {}^{(X,1)}\pi_{ab}^c = \frac12 g^{cd} \left( \nabla_a {}^{(X,0)}\pi_{bd} + \nabla_b {}^{(X,0)}\pi_{ad} - \nabla_d {}^{(X,0)}\pi_{ab} \right) $$
from this you see that for the commutator to vanish identically it is necessary and sufficient that $X$ is Killing.

Comment: It seems to me that there should be a calculation-free argument. Something based on the fact that the Laplacian uniquely determines the metric. So if the Laplacian commutes with the vector field, then so does the metric.

Comment: @DeaneYang: yes. But then you need the fact that the Laplacian uniquely determines the metric. Which you get by looking at its principal part, and then we come back to Tobias' comments. (In any case, if you are talking about my tendency to provide lowbrow answers on MO, I am definitely guilty as charged. :-p)

Comment: Willie, I certainly wasn't knocking your "lowbrow" answer. That's the best kind, especially for anyone learning things the first time. I was just wondering about a more precise way to express the fact that we all knew in advance that the vector field had to be Killing.

Comment: @WillieWong  Is  there  a  Riemannian  metric  on $\mathbb{R}^2 $  or  the  punctured  plane  such that  the  vander pol  vector  field  would  be  a  Killing vector  field. In  this  case the  space  of  Harmonic maps  would  be  invariant under  flow then  one  can think  to  compute  the  algebraic   index of  such operator (to  have  some  dynamical  information on X)

Comment: I'm afraid I am not familiar with "the" Van der Pol vector field. Can you tell me what it is? @AliTaghavi

Comment: @WillieWong  It  is  the  following  vector  field  on  the  plane: $x'=y-(x^3-x), \;  y'=-x$. It  is  well known that  it  has  a  unique  limit  cycle.

Comment: @WillieWong  Assume  that  $X$ is  a  Killing  vector  field. Then is  it  true  that the  flow  of  $X$  is  volume  preserving?(The  volume  corresponding to the metric)  If  yes  existence  of  attractor is  an  obstruction  to  extestence  of  a  metric  for  which  X, the  Van Der  pol, would  be  a  Killing  vector  field.

Comment: To  be  honest,  since  13  years  ago I  try  to  find  an operator associated with  a  vector  field  which contains  some  information  about the  dynamics  of  $X$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: the flow of a Killing vector field is a one-parameter family of isometries. So it is volume preserving.