# Is the space of harmonic functions invariant under the derivational operator associated with a geodesible flow?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Assume that $V$ is a vector field on a 
Riemannian  manifold $(M,g)$ with natural  volume form $\Omega$ arising from $g$.
Assume that the solution curves of $V$ are parametrized geodesics of the Riemannian metric $g$.

> Is it true to say that the space of harmonic functions is invariant under the derivational operator $D(f)=V.f=df(V)$?

The  question is related to the following post

[Vector Fields in a Riemannian Manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215288/vector-fields-in-a-riemannian-manifold/215300#comment671908_215300)

Comment: You mean $Vf = 0$?

Comment: No, that is not true, but likely you made a mistake in formulation --- since you mention $\Omega$ , you probably wanted to use it...

Comment: @AntonPetrunin  $\Omega $ is  used to define  the  Laplacian $\Delta=Div \circ \nabla$, so I think it is necessary and  depend on the metric. but  what is  a  counter example?

Comment: @JohnMa  No  I  do  not  mean "$Vf=0"$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a [warped product](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0236.pdf) $M=\mathbb S^1\times_f\mathbb S^1$ for a nonconstant smooth function $f$.

The horizontal vector field $V$ satisfies your condition,
but for harmonic function is not invariant $f$, the function $Vf$ is not harmonic.

To see this, consider the $V$-flow $\Phi^t\colon M\to M$.
If $Vf$ is always harmonic then so is $f\circ\Phi^t$ for any $t$.
The latter fails evidently.

Comment: Thank you  very  much for  your  answer.I try to understand the details.